# JMeter test setup

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, stress

I have a problem with setup my stress test.
I need auto increasing accesses on HTTP web page, stop test when load time of page will be more than 10 seconds and track number of accesses at this point.
Can someone help me, please?

A tried it with Concurency Thread group

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Gradually increasing load can be simulated using any [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) even the "normal" one via Ramp-up period input field

   [image]
2. You can stop the test in 2 ways:

   - using [Auto Stop Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) (however it will track the average response time)

     [image]
   - using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code:

     ```
       if(prev.getTime() >= 10000) {
           prev.setStopTest(true)
           log.info('Number of threads when response time exceeded 10 seconds was: ' + ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumberOfThreads())
       }
     ```
3. The number of active threads at any given moment of time using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener or the equivalent chart from [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) or last line of the above Groovy code